# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location' from a pickled class

Tags: python

I have a simple player class for a text based game

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.location = "start"
        self.hp = 100

    def save(self):
        pickle.dump(self, open("_SaveFile.pkl", "wb"))

    def load(self):
        if Path("_SaveFile.pkl", "rb").is_file():
            with open("_SaveFile.pkl", "rb") as f:
                character = pickle.load(f)
                return character

    def isAlive(self):
        return self.hp > 0
```

and want to pickle the class and then be able to deserialise it to load the player data back into the game (for saving and loading the game)

I have the following code in the main menu of the game to use the character to access player variables

```
player = Player().load()
```

I would expect this to just assign the returned value of character to player into the player variable.

I tried to use pickle.load(filepath) to load the data but when I try to access the location variable it returns the following error.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'

How can I access the location variable

Comment: Are you sure the opickle was saved ok? Try to use `with open(...` to do the save as you did to do the read. In that way you are sure that the file has been properly closed

Comment: Your `load` method is always returning None, because your check for the file's existence is always failing.  `Path("_SaveFile.pkl", "rb")` is nonsense (it's actually referring to a file *named* `rb` in a folder named `_SaveFile.pkl`), get rid of that second parameter.